# Multivariable Calculus - Exercise about Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I need your help with the following exercise:

The sphere $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=4$ is made of certain material whose density is given by $\rho(x,y,z)=y^{2}+xy+2$. I need to find the extreme values of $\rho(x,y,z)$ using the Lagrange multiplier method.

If $g(x,y,z) = x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}-4=0$, $\rho_{x}(x,y,z) = y$, $\rho_{y}(x,y,z)=2y+x$, and $\rho_{z}(z,y,z) =0$, then

$$ \begin{align}y &= 2x\lambda \tag{EQ 1} \\
2y+x &= 2y\lambda \tag{EQ 2} \\
0 &= 2z\lambda \tag{EQ 3} \\
x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}-4&= 0 \tag{EQ 4} \end{align} $$

I'm having trouble solving this system of equations because I'm getting $\lambda=0$ from the third equation.

What does it mean?
Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the third equation you know that either $\lambda=0$ or $z=0$.

Comment: @GReyes This is my confusion: since $z$ is on the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$, I thought that $z$ must be non-zero.

Comment: The entire equator consists of points where $z = 0$, so they satisfy the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: You can even have two coordinates simultaneously equal to zero, e.g., $x = y = 0$ describes the pair of points satisfying $z^2 = 4$, i.e., the poles $z = \pm 2$. But you cannot have **all three** coordinates simultaneously vanish because then $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 0 \neq 4$.

Comment: Ok. I get it now. Thanks @SammyBlack

Answer (score 1):

OP has derived these :
$$ \begin{align}y &= 2x\lambda \tag{EQ 1} \\
2y+x &= 2y\lambda \tag{EQ 2} \\
0 &= 2z\lambda \tag{EQ 3} \\
x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}-4&= 0 \tag{EQ 4} \end{align} $$

With EQ3 , we get [CASE 1] $\lambda = 0$ or [CASE 2] $z=0$

[CASE 1] then gives $y=0$ , $x=0$ , $z=\pm2$
At these Points , $\rho=0+0+2$

[CASE 2] gives something else.
Plug EQ 1 in EQ 2 to get $2 \times 2x\lambda + x = 2 \times 2x\lambda \times \lambda $
$4 \lambda + 1 = 4 \lambda^2 $
$\lambda = [1 \pm \sqrt{2}]/2$
With that , we then get $x$ & $y$ values (Due to Quadratic Equation & 2 values for $\lambda$ , we get four Solution Points involving $\pm \sqrt{2}$)
We then evaluate $\rho$ , which is $4$ (at all Solution Points) :
[image: MAX]
[[ generated by Wolfram Online Tool ]]

OVER-VIEW :
[CASE 1] is the Extrema $2$ which occurs at the top & bottom of the Sphere
[CASE 2] is the Extrema $4$ , which occurs Symmetrically on the $XY$ Plane

ERRATA :

The above corresponds to $\rho=x^2+xy+2$ which has a typo.
This corresponds to the correct $\rho=y^2+xy+2$ :

[image: ERRATA]

Thus we have multiple relative local Extrema values , while $\rho=6.82843$ is the over-all maxima.

CORRECT OVER-VIEW :
[CASE 1] has the local Extrema $\rho=2$ which occurs at the top & bottom of the Sphere
[CASE 2] has the local Extrema $\rho=1.17157$ & $\rho=6.82843$ , which occurs Symmetrically on the $XY$ Plane